# Qt3DRender : How to render an isosurface from quadrilateral patches?

Tags: c++, 3d, qt3d

I extracted an isosurface with the [dual marching cubes algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4112407_Dual_Marching_Cubes).

From the algorithm, I got the following data:

```
# cube.obj wavefront file
## shared vertices (cartesian coordinates)
v 1.0 1.0 0.0
v 0.0 1.0 0.0
v 0.0 0.0 0.0
v 1.0 0.0 0.0
v 1.0 0.0 1.0
v 0.0 0.0 1.0
v 0.0 1.0 1.0
v 1.0 1.0 1.0
## faces (vertex indices are forming quad patches)
f 1 4 3 2
f 5 6 3 4
f 7 2 3 6
f 8 5 4 1
f 8 1 2 7
f 8 7 6 5
```

(Plotting triangulated surfaces is explained [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/examples/qt3d/custom-mesh-cpp/main.cpp?h=5.6)).

**Main question:** Is it possible to render an isosurface from this quadrilateral face data with Qt3d?

**Bonus question:** How can I make the surface transparent or plot it as a wireframe?

This is how far I got:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QOrbitCameraController>
#include <Qt3DRender/QCamera>
#include <Qt3DCore/QEntity>
#include <Qt3DCore/QTransform>
#include <Qt3DRender/QGeometryRenderer>
#include <Qt3DRender/QAttribute>
#include <Qt3DRender/QBuffer>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QPhongAlphaMaterial>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Root entity
    auto *rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();

    // Window container
    auto qt3DWindow = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();
    qt3DWindow->setRootEntity(rootEntity);
    auto widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(qt3DWindow);

    // Camera
    auto *camController = new Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController(rootEntity);

    qt3DWindow->setRootEntity(rootEntity);
    qt3DWindow->camera()->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 16.0f / 9.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    qt3DWindow->camera()->setPosition(QVector3D(2.5, -8, 0.0));
    qt3DWindow->camera()->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    // For camera controls
    camController->setLinearSpeed(50.f);
    camController->setLookSpeed(180.f);
    camController->setCamera(qt3DWindow->camera());

    // Material
    auto *material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongAlphaMaterial(rootEntity);
    material->setSpecular(Qt::white);
    material->setShininess(0);
    material->setAmbient(Qt::red);
    material->setAlpha(0.5);

    // Transform
    auto *transform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
    transform->setScale(1.0f);

    auto *customMeshEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);

    // Custom Mesh
    auto *customMeshRenderer = new Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer;
    auto *customGeometry = new Qt3DRender::QGeometry(customMeshRenderer);

    auto *vertexDataBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(Qt3DRender::QBuffer::VertexBuffer, customGeometry);
    auto *indexDataBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(Qt3DRender::QBuffer::IndexBuffer, customGeometry);

    // Vertices
    auto nVertices = 8;
    auto nCoordinates = 3; // cartesian coordinates
    QByteArray vertexBufferData;
    vertexBufferData.resize(nVertices * nCoordinates * sizeof(float));

    auto *rawVertexArray = reinterpret_cast<float *>(vertexBufferData.data());
    // Vertex 1
    rawVertexArray[0*nCoordinates+0] = 1.0f;
    rawVertexArray[0*nCoordinates+1] = 1.0f;
    rawVertexArray[0*nCoordinates+2] = 0.0f;
    // Vertex 2
    rawVertexArray[1*nCoordinates+0] = 0.0f;
    rawVertexArray[1*nCoordinates+1] = 1.0f;
    rawVertexArray[1*nCoordinates+2] = 0.0f;
    // Vertex 3
    rawVertexArray[2*nCoordinates+0] = 0.0f;
    rawVertexArray[2*nCoordinates+1] = 0.0f;
    rawVertexArray[2*nCoordinates+2] = 0.0f;
    // Vertex 4
    rawVertexArray[3*nCoordinates+0] = 1.0f;
    rawVertexArray[3*nCoordinates+1] = 0.0f;
    rawVertexArray[3*nCoordinates+2] = 0.0f;
    // Vertex 5
    rawVertexArray[4*nCoordinates+0] = 1.0f;
    rawVertexArray[4*nCoordinates+1] = 0.0f;
    rawVertexArray[4*nCoordinates+2] = 1.0f;
    // Vertex 6
    rawVertexArray[5*nCoordinates+0] = 0.0f;
    rawVertexArray[5*nCoordinates+1] = 0.0f;
    rawVertexArray[5*nCoordinates+2] = 1.0f;
    // Vertex 7
    rawVertexArray[6*nCoordinates+0] = 0.0f;
    rawVertexArray[6*nCoordinates+1] = 1.0f;
    rawVertexArray[6*nCoordinates+2] = 1.0f;
    // Vertex 8
    rawVertexArray[7*nCoordinates+0] = 1.0f;
    rawVertexArray[7*nCoordinates+1] = 1.0f;
    rawVertexArray[7*nCoordinates+2] = 1.0f;

    vertexDataBuffer->setData(vertexBufferData);

    // Faces
    unsigned nFaces = 6;
    unsigned nIndicesPerFace = 4;
    QByteArray indexBufferData;
    indexBufferData.resize(nFaces * nIndicesPerFace * sizeof(ushort));

    auto *rawIndexArray = reinterpret_cast<ushort *>(indexBufferData.data());
    // Face 1
    rawIndexArray[0*nIndicesPerFace+0] = 1;
    rawIndexArray[0*nIndicesPerFace+1] = 4;
    rawIndexArray[0*nIndicesPerFace+2] = 3;
    rawIndexArray[0*nIndicesPerFace+3] = 2;
    // Face 2
    rawIndexArray[1*nIndicesPerFace+0] = 5;
    rawIndexArray[1*nIndicesPerFace+1] = 6;
    rawIndexArray[1*nIndicesPerFace+2] = 3;
    rawIndexArray[1*nIndicesPerFace+3] = 4;
    // Face 3
    rawIndexArray[2*nIndicesPerFace+0] = 7;
    rawIndexArray[2*nIndicesPerFace+1] = 2;
    rawIndexArray[2*nIndicesPerFace+2] = 3;
    rawIndexArray[2*nIndicesPerFace+3] = 6;
    // Face 4
    rawIndexArray[3*nIndicesPerFace+0] = 8;
    rawIndexArray[3*nIndicesPerFace+1] = 5;
    rawIndexArray[3*nIndicesPerFace+2] = 4;
    rawIndexArray[3*nIndicesPerFace+3] = 1;
    // Face 5
    rawIndexArray[4*nIndicesPerFace+0] = 8;
    rawIndexArray[4*nIndicesPerFace+1] = 1;
    rawIndexArray[4*nIndicesPerFace+2] = 2;
    rawIndexArray[4*nIndicesPerFace+3] = 7;
    // Face 6
    rawIndexArray[5*nIndicesPerFace+0] = 8;
    rawIndexArray[5*nIndicesPerFace+1] = 7;
    rawIndexArray[5*nIndicesPerFace+2] = 6;
    rawIndexArray[5*nIndicesPerFace+3] = 5;

    indexDataBuffer->setData(indexBufferData);

    // Attributes
    auto *positionAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute();
    positionAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    positionAttribute->setBuffer(vertexDataBuffer);
    positionAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
    positionAttribute->setDataSize(3);
    positionAttribute->setByteOffset(0);
    positionAttribute->setByteStride(3 * sizeof(float));
    positionAttribute->setCount(nVertices);
    positionAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName());

    auto *indexAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute();
    indexAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::IndexAttribute);
    indexAttribute->setBuffer(indexDataBuffer);
    indexAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::UnsignedShort);
    indexAttribute->setDataSize(1);
    indexAttribute->setByteOffset(0);
    indexAttribute->setByteStride(0);
    indexAttribute->setCount(nFaces*nIndicesPerFace);

    customGeometry->addAttribute(positionAttribute);
    customGeometry->addAttribute(indexAttribute);

    customMeshRenderer->setInstanceCount(1);
    customMeshRenderer->setFirstVertex(0);
    customMeshRenderer->setIndexOffset(1); // first index is 1
    customMeshRenderer->setFirstInstance(0);
    customMeshRenderer->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Patches);
    customMeshRenderer->setVerticesPerPatch(4);
    customMeshRenderer->setGeometry(customGeometry);
    customMeshRenderer->setVertexCount(nFaces * nIndicesPerFace);

    customMeshEntity->addComponent(customMeshRenderer);
    customMeshEntity->addComponent(transform);
    customMeshEntity->addComponent(material);

    qt3DWindow->setRootEntity(rootEntity);
    widget->show();

    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

The rendered scene remains empty, so I assume I did something wrong here. 
I am grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out the solution. Following the suggestion of @peppe, I plotted triangles. I also calculated the vertex normals.

Here the code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QOrbitCameraController>
#include <Qt3DRender/QCamera>
#include <Qt3DCore/QEntity>
#include <Qt3DCore/QTransform>
#include <Qt3DRender/QGeometryRenderer>
#include <Qt3DRender/QAttribute>
#include <Qt3DRender/QBuffer>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QPhongAlphaMaterial>

#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <utility>

struct Vertex{

    Vertex(QVector3D p, ushort id)
    : position(p), normal({0,0,0}), index(id){}

    QVector3D position, normal;
    ushort index;
};

struct Quad{
    Quad() = delete;
    explicit Quad(std::vector<Vertex> v)
            : vertices(v) {
        assert(vertices.size() == 4);
    }

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
};
struct Triangle{
    Triangle() = delete;
    explicit Triangle(std::vector<Vertex> v)
    : vertices(v), faceNormal(QVector3D::normal(v[0].position,v[1].position,v[2].position)) {
        assert(vertices.size() == 3);
    }

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    QVector3D faceNormal;
};

using trianlgePair = std::pair<Triangle,Triangle>;

trianlgePair quadToTriangle(Quad quad) {
    return {Triangle({quad.vertices[0], quad.vertices[1], quad.vertices[2]}),
            Triangle({quad.vertices[2], quad.vertices[3], quad.vertices[0]})};
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<Vertex>vertices({
        Vertex({1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}, 1-1),
        Vertex({0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}, 2-1),
        Vertex({0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, 3-1),
        Vertex({1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, 4-1),
        Vertex({1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, 5-1),
        Vertex({0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, 6-1),
        Vertex({0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, 7-1),
        Vertex({1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, 8-1)
    });

    std::vector<Quad> quads({
        Quad({vertices[1-1], vertices[4-1], vertices[3-1], vertices[2-1]}),
        Quad({vertices[5-1], vertices[6-1], vertices[3-1], vertices[4-1]}),
        Quad({vertices[7-1], vertices[2-1], vertices[3-1], vertices[6-1]}),
        Quad({vertices[8-1], vertices[5-1], vertices[4-1], vertices[1-1]}),
        Quad({vertices[8-1], vertices[1-1], vertices[2-1], vertices[7-1]}),
        Quad({vertices[8-1], vertices[7-1], vertices[6-1], vertices[5-1]})
    });
    unsigned nCoordinates = 3; // cartesian coordinates

    // Triangles
    std::vector<Triangle> triangles;
    for(const auto& quad : quads){

        auto trianglePair = quadToTriangle(quad);

        triangles.push_back(trianglePair.first);
        triangles.push_back(trianglePair.second);
    }
    unsigned nIndicesPerTriangle= 3;

    // vertex normals
    for (auto it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it) {

        QVector3D vertexNormal = {0,0,0};

        // find triangles that contain the vertex
        for(const auto& t : triangles) {
            if(std::find_if(t.vertices.begin(), t.vertices.end(),
                    [it](const Vertex& v)->bool { return v.index == it.base()->index; }
                    ) != t.vertices.end())
                vertexNormal += t.faceNormal;
        }

        it.base()->normal = vertexNormal.normalized();
    }


    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Root entity
    auto *rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();

    // Window container
    auto qt3DWindow = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();
    qt3DWindow->setRootEntity(rootEntity);
    auto widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(qt3DWindow);

    // Camera
    auto *camController = new Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController(rootEntity);

    qt3DWindow->setRootEntity(rootEntity);
    qt3DWindow->camera()->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 16.0f / 9.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    qt3DWindow->camera()->setPosition(QVector3D(2.5, -8, 0.0));
    qt3DWindow->camera()->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    // For camera controls
    camController->setLinearSpeed(50.f);
    camController->setLookSpeed(180.f);
    camController->setCamera(qt3DWindow->camera());

    // Material
    auto *material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongAlphaMaterial(rootEntity);
    material->setSpecular(Qt::white);
    material->setShininess(0);
    material->setAmbient(Qt::red);
    material->setAlpha(0.5);

    // Transform
    auto *transform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
    transform->setScale(1.0f);

    auto *customMeshEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);

    // Custom Mesh
    auto *customMeshRenderer = new Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer;
    auto *customGeometry = new Qt3DRender::QGeometry(customMeshRenderer);

    auto *vertexDataBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(Qt3DRender::QBuffer::VertexBuffer, customGeometry);
    auto *indexDataBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(Qt3DRender::QBuffer::IndexBuffer, customGeometry);

    // Vertices
    auto vertexDataPackageSize = nCoordinates*2; // position + normal
    QByteArray vertexBufferData;
    vertexBufferData.resize(vertices.size() * vertexDataPackageSize * sizeof(float));
    auto *rawVertexArray = reinterpret_cast<float *>(vertexBufferData.data());

    int idx = 0;
    for (const auto & v : vertices) {
        rawVertexArray[idx++] = float(v.position[0]);
        rawVertexArray[idx++] = float(v.position[1]);
        rawVertexArray[idx++] = float(v.position[2]);

        rawVertexArray[idx++] = float(v.normal[0]);
        rawVertexArray[idx++] = float(v.normal[1]);
        rawVertexArray[idx++] = float(v.normal[2]);
    }
    vertexDataBuffer->setData(vertexBufferData);

    auto *positionAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute();
    positionAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    positionAttribute->setBuffer(vertexDataBuffer);
    positionAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
    positionAttribute->setDataSize(nCoordinates);
    positionAttribute->setByteOffset(0);
    positionAttribute->setByteStride(vertexDataPackageSize  * sizeof(float));
    positionAttribute->setCount(vertices.size());
    positionAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName());

    auto *normalAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute();
    normalAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    normalAttribute->setBuffer(vertexDataBuffer);
    normalAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
    normalAttribute->setDataSize(nCoordinates);
    normalAttribute->setByteOffset(nCoordinates * sizeof(float));
    normalAttribute->setByteStride(vertexDataPackageSize * sizeof(float));
    normalAttribute->setCount(vertices.size());
    normalAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultNormalAttributeName());

    QByteArray indexBufferData;
    indexBufferData.resize(triangles.size() * nIndicesPerTriangle * sizeof(ushort));
    auto *rawIndexArray = reinterpret_cast<ushort *>(indexBufferData.data());
    idx = 0;
    for (const auto& t : triangles) {

        rawIndexArray[idx++] = t.vertices[0].index;
        rawIndexArray[idx++] = t.vertices[1].index;
        rawIndexArray[idx++] = t.vertices[2].index;
        //std::cout << t.vertices[0].index <<", "<< t.vertices[1].index <<", "<< t.vertices[2].index << std::endl;
    }
    indexDataBuffer->setData(indexBufferData);

    auto *indexAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute();
    indexAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::IndexAttribute);
    indexAttribute->setBuffer(indexDataBuffer);
    indexAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::UnsignedShort);
    indexAttribute->setDataSize(1);
    indexAttribute->setByteOffset(0);
    indexAttribute->setByteStride(0);
    indexAttribute->setCount(triangles.size()*nIndicesPerTriangle);

    customMeshRenderer->setInstanceCount(1);
    customMeshRenderer->setFirstVertex(0);
    customMeshRenderer->setIndexOffset(0);
    customMeshRenderer->setFirstInstance(0);
    customMeshRenderer->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Triangles);
    customMeshRenderer->setGeometry(customGeometry);
    customMeshRenderer->setVertexCount(triangles.size()*nIndicesPerTriangle);
    customGeometry->addAttribute(positionAttribute);
    customGeometry->addAttribute(normalAttribute);
    customGeometry->addAttribute(indexAttribute);

    customMeshEntity->addComponent(customMeshRenderer);
    customMeshEntity->addComponent(transform);
    customMeshEntity->addComponent(material);

    qt3DWindow->setRootEntity(rootEntity);
    widget->show();

    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"Patch" in OpenGL has a very specific meaning (patches have to do with [tessellation shaders](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation#Patches), which you aren't using).

Here you're simply dealing with faces which are quadrilaterals. In order to render them, you need to split them in two triangles (modern OpenGL does not render quads any longer). Note that if you've got a .obj file, you can use QMesh / QSceneLoader to load the file directly...

Comment: I already tried loading the .obj file but QMesh doesn't seem to understand the quad data format. Furthermore, I don't want to do file I/O. I want to visualize the data directl.

Comment: I tried to follow your idea with plotting triangles but I am struggling with the indexing of the vertices. Can somebody point me to literature or provide other help on how to convert the quad indices into triangle indices?